# My drag and drop function isn't working. I'm getting a TypeError. What does this mean?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, drag

I'm getting an error stating:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null,

I'm trying to make a drag and drop game with pizza images and I'm struggling to get anything to drag and drop anywhere on my HTML. I can't figure out why my `addEventListener` is null when I created an HTML for it.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="outerContainer">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="item">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html

<script>

var dragItem = document.querySelector("#item");
var container = document.querySelector("#container");

var active = false;
var currentX;
var currentY;
var initialX;
var initialY;
var xOffset = 0;
var yOffset = 0;


container.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
container.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
container.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);
```

Comment: Missing a `>` on your closing html tag

Answer (score 1):

You should try putting the javascript code in a function and call that function on onload event. This is to make sure that the DOM is loaded when the javascript gets executed.

```
<html>
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="outerContainer">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="item">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>

function init() {
    var dragItem = document.querySelector("#item");
    var container = document.querySelector("#container");

    var active = false;
    var currentX;
    var currentY;
    var initialX;
    var initialY;
    var xOffset = 0;
    var yOffset = 0;

    container.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
    container.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
    container.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);
}
</script>
```